# Using Ubuntu Font doesn't work with special characters on iOS

Tags: ios, fonts

I am using the Ubuntu font family (http://font.ubuntu.com/) within my iOS app, which works great except with a mdesh (and propably some more characters, the mdesh is the one I am having trouble right now).

Using the font within Word or on a website the charcater appears correctly, I took also a look inside the font and the character ist there.

You can test it by yourself on http://font.ubuntu.com/ by pasting

> Der Halbgeviertstrich (–) ist in der Typografie ein waagerechter
>   Strich,

into the input field.

I have also ensured that there is no other cause, the text ist correctly stored in SQLite and correctly set to the text property of an UILabel control (so the mdesh is there at this point in time).

So the font seems to be okay, my code seems to be okay, but I don't get it to work.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem with this font, but only with some special characters, not all. In French. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, I have still the same problem. Maybe we should report it to the Ubuntu guys who made the font.

Comment: That would be useful. But for my project I switched to another font...

Comment: Did you find a similar one? Which one?

Comment: I would like to use the Karbon font, but I'm currently checking if its license is compatible with mobile apps. I can post here more infos when I get them, if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks, yes, let me know. Licensing was exactly the reason why we decided to chose Ubuntu, because font licensing is otherwise a mafia business ;-).

Comment: So it's possible to use the Karbon font in mobile apps. As it's not publicly available on their [website](https://klim.co.nz/retail-fonts/karbon/), I prefer not to give more infos here regarding the pricing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the font itself, not the OS that limitates the available characters. Ubuntu seems not to have a dash on OS X either.

Comment: Which specific Ubuntu TrueType font files are you referring to? I found that all of those TrueType font files do actually contain an endash and an emdash, but that there is an odd bug with `Ubuntu-R.ttf` (Ubuntu Regular) which causes a `LATIN SMALL LETTER W WITH ACUTE` (ẃ) to be displayed instead of the proper –. Is this what you're referring to? That is odd... Not sure if that's a problem with the font or a bug in OS X (and therefore iOS as well).

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what is happening. I am usually using Ubuntu Regular. I haven't tried to use Ubuntu Medium or Bold.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like on iOS 10 and onwards it is able to render on single line uilabel. However rendering fails if it is a multiline label.